# Draw arrow outside plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following gridded plot, and would like to draw an arrow (shown in blue using MS paint). How can I do it through matplotlib? I do not know of any command to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fg = plt.figure(1);
fg.clf();
ax = fg.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.annotate('', xy=(0, -0.1), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(1, -0.1), 
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<->", color='b'))
ax.grid(True)
fg.canvas.draw()
```

gives [image]

Comment: So you specify the end of the arrow by saying where the (nonexistent) box goes. Oh, I need you, but I do not love you, matplotlib.  [plotting-by-side-effect](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27240/alternative-to-matplotlib-for-scientific-plotting-with-python) indeed.  But +1 for solution, thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Use `clip_on = False` in `ax.arrow`