# Matplotlib: How to get a colour-gradient as an arrow next to a plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am trying to create a plot with `matplotlib` that includes several different lines, offset artificially, that are coloured according to the RedBlue colourmap `mpl.cm.RdBu`. Now I want an arrow next to the plot that acts as an effective colourscale, meaning that it should have a colour gradient.

So far, I have managed to create the arrow itself using `annotate` with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922804/draw-arrow-outside-plot-in-matplotlib/23923096) and drew a "Rainbow arrow" inside the plot using [this brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47165448/5679295) (Note: You will need matplotlib `2.2.4` or older to run this part of the code, see comments.).

This is the MWE I can produce so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms
import matplotlib.path
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

# from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163796/using-colormap-with-annotate-arrow-in-matplotlib
def rainbowarrow(ax, start, end, cmap="viridis", n=50,lw=3):
    cmap = plt.get_cmap(cmap,n)
    # Arrow shaft: LineCollection
    x = np.linspace(start[0],end[0],n)
    y = np.linspace(start[1],end[1],n)
    points = np.array([x,y]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
    segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1],points[1:]], axis=1)
    lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap, linewidth=lw)
    lc.set_array(np.linspace(0,1,n))
    ax.add_collection(lc)
    # Arrow head: Triangle
    tricoords = [(0,-0.4),(0.5,0),(0,0.4),(0,-0.4)]
    angle = np.arctan2(end[1]-start[1],end[0]-start[0])
    rot = matplotlib.transforms.Affine2D().rotate(angle)
    tricoords2 = rot.transform(tricoords)
    tri = matplotlib.path.Path(tricoords2, closed=True)
    ax.scatter(end[0],end[1], c=1, s=(2*lw)**2, marker=tri, cmap=cmap,vmin=0)
    ax.autoscale_view()

def plot_arrow(data,n):
    fig, subfig = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(6.28,10)) # plotsize, etc
    colorP=mpl.cm.RdBu(0.2)

    i = 0
    while i<=n-1:
        subfig.plot(data[i,0], (data[i,1])+i, lw=2, color=mpl.cm.RdBu(1-i/20)) # plot of data
        i=i+1

    subfig.annotate('', xy=(1.1,0), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(1.1,1), 
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<-", lw = 3))
    subfig.annotate('A', xy=(1.1,0), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(1.1,1))
    subfig.annotate('B', xy=(1.1,0), xycoords='axes fraction', xytext=(1.1,0))

    rainbowarrow(subfig, (1.1,3), (1.1,5), cmap='RdBu_r', n=100,lw=3)

    plt.show(fig)
    plt.close(fig)


# things to plot
np.random.seed(19680802)
n = 20
i = 0
data = np.empty([n,2,10])
while i<=n-1:
    data[i]=np.sin(np.random.rand(10))
    i = i+1

# actual plot
plot_arrow(data,n)
```

Here's the graph generated:

[image: Resulting matplotlib plot]

In a nutshell: I want the annotation arrow outside the plot to have the colour of the colourmap, as the small rainbow arrow inside the plot.

Comment: I get a `IndexError: tuple index out of range` error on the `ax.scatter` line in function `rainbowarrow`.

Comment: @cronburg That's strange, the code compiles fine for me... I use Python 3 in a Jupyter Notebook on Debian 9, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: I've added the graph for you, which I was able to run with matplotlib `2.2.4` on python2. Note that newer versions of matplotlib will break the [code you adapted from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163796/using-colormap-with-annotate-arrow-in-matplotlib/47165448#47165448) (I was running `3.0.3`) because `ax.scatter` appears to no longer accepts floating point / integer types as the first two arguments (it only accepts array-like things now [as per the docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html)).

Comment: @cronburg Thanks for adding the graph (although the lines all appear with the same colour now). I didn't know I was using an outdated version of `matplotlib`...

Comment: at least that's the only explanation I have for my different behavior. You can check your version with `print("Matplotlib version:", matplotlib.__version__)`, but it likely won't affect your question - your question sounds answerable regardless.

Comment: @cronburg Yes, I am using `2.0.0` :O. I will add this info to the main question.